# How to store Python dictonary with tuple as keys without changing structure of dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

Problem:
I'm trying to store a python dictionary which has tuples as keys, I didn't tried to change structure of dictionary because a value in this dictionary can be another dictionary. I tried using Json but since it only supports string type keys, it failed.

Structure of the dictionary:

```
dict[(s1,s2)] = f
```

where s1,s2 -> strings, f->float

How do I store this dictionary as a file.

Comment: Side note: don't name variables after classes, use `d` or `dict_` instead of `dict`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json dumping a dict gives TypeError: keys must be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734517/json-dumping-a-dict-gives-typeerror-keys-must-be-a-string)

Comment: You could just write the string repersentation to a file, and then use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the contents of that file back to a python object.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to save the object for later, then you could use pickle. Try this:

```
import pickle

a = {('a','b') : 1.2}
pickle.dump(a, open('test.pickle','w'))
b = pickle.load(open('test.pickle','r'))

print a
# {('a', 'b'): 1.2}
print b
# {('a', 'b'): 1.2}
```